# Is there a probability distribution associated with an uncertainty range?

Tags: probability, rounding-error

Let's say I measure the length of a table to be 1.25 metres and the width to be 0.65 metres. Both measurements are accurate to the nearest cm.

Then the area of the table would be calculated as:

$$(1.25m)(0.65 m ) = 0.8125m^2$$

Standard practice is to give the final answer as $0.81 \pm 0.01m^2$ as that is the level of the accuracy of the given data.

Taking max values of: $$(1.255m)(0.655m ) = 0.822025m^2$$

and min values of $$(1.245m)(0.645m ) = 0.803025m^2$$

we get a result of $$0.812525 \pm 0.009500 m^2$$

My question is: Is there a probability distribution associated with the range $$0.812525 \pm 0.009500 m^2$$

I mean surely the chances of all values being max values or min values is much less than the chances of the values being nearer to the mean value.

Comment: There are infinitely many distributions that can be associated with that interval notation. It depends both on what you mean by the interval and how you model the measurement errors. We need more details about your model and what you're trying to achieve with it.

Comment: @RiccardoSvenRisuleo But I've included both ''what I mean by the interval'' and ''how I modeled the measurement errors''. What else do you need to answer my question ? Please be specific and I'll add it to my question.